# How come my recursive function won't get called from promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, nightmare

I can't get my function to get called recursively no matter what I do. I've tried returning and storing into a variable and many other things but it only ever gets called once?

```
 var scrape = () => {
    var waitTime = randomIntFromInterval(1000, 10000);

    nightmare.goto('http://...') 
      .wait(waitTime)
      .evaluate(() => {
        var data = [];
        // ... doing work to get data from browser here
        return data
      })
      .end()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('scraped successfully!' + new Date());
        scrape();
      }
    )
  }

  scrape();
```

**I thought the final `.then()` means that the promise is complete and has succeeded?**

**UPDATE:**

**It seems removing `.end()` has solved my issue. I do not fully understand the nightmare docs as https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare and it says that it completes any queue operations. I pulled some of code from an example and it had `end()` in there. Will I experience any implications from removing this?**

Comment: Does `'scraped successfully!'` get printed? Also, if you uncomment `return result`, the function there will end before calling `scrape`.

Comment: `return scrape()` inside the last .then?

Comment: Yes, the console.log gets called but only once

Comment: @JaromandaX that didn't work either. And yes I know I was just playing around and forgot to remove the commented out return.

Comment: of course, if you do return there, then the promise will never "complete", because it recurses unconditionally

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah I didn't initially have that return there. I'm stumped why my function is only called once?

Comment: Maybe add a `catch` to see if an error is being thrown?

Comment: @Taylor - You can provide an answer to your own question if you solved it.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I know. I just don't really know if I solved it haha... I will if after a bit more playing around I don't encounter any weird issues! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of the needed for `.end`, but I'm absolutely sure that you need add `return scrape()` inside the last `.then` and `return` before `nightmare.goto`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this flow,

```
var scrape = () => {
var waitTime = randomIntFromInterval(1000, 10000);

nightmare.goto('http://...') 

  .then((result) => {
    console.log('scraped successfully!' + new Date());

    ////do the end process here////

    scrape();
  }
  )
 }

 scrape();
```

Comment: I don't think changing the syntax will help... I updated my code.

Comment: your answer pointed me in the direction to make an advancement. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Append a psuedo-random hash to the end of your URL, like `#' + new Date().getTime()`. If that works for you, then you're probably running into [this issue](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/676) where using nightmare's `.goTo()` to navigate to the same URL results in a no-op.

Comment: I removed `.end()` from my code and it seems to be working now... I don't fully understand if removing this will have implications?